# Can't get Angular-xeditable Editable-Select to Select the current item when it is bound to a nested JSON object

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I can't get the Angular-xeditable Editable-Select to Select the current item when it is bound to a nested JSON object.  Data all saves fine, but it just doesn't show up the currently selected item in the Select box, which is driving me nuts, as I am sure I am missing something obvious. I have created a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/1031/

This is the code:

```
<span editable-select="data.organisation.OrganisationType"
              e-ng-options="type.Name for type in data.types">
            {{data.organisation.OrganisationType.Name}}
        </span>
```

These are the 2 data objects:

```
$scope.data.organisation =  {
"Id":1,
"Name":"My Organisation",
"OrganisationType":{"Id":2,"Name":"Internal"}
 } 

$scope.data.types = [
{"Id":1,"Name":"Client"},
{"Id":2,"Name":"Internal"},
{"Id":3,"Name":"Cold"}
]
```

It works fine when I bind it to the ID within the Nested Object, but then it only changes the Id in my nested object, and I then have to manually filter and change the Name part of the object, which works, but I am sure there must be a better way.

Comment: Try ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in data.types" ?

Comment: Try ng-options="type.Id as type.Name for type in data.types"

Answer (score 1):

When the item is selected $data is loaded with the id of the item selected. You can use this to retrieve the value after the selection is made.

```
<span editable-select="data.organisation.OrganisationType"
      e-ng-options="type.Name for type in data.types">
  {{ findTypeName($data) || data.organisation.OrganisationType.Name}}
</span>
```

You can then define findTypeName in your controller

```
$scope.findTypeName = function(id) {
  var found = $scope.data.types.filter(function(t){
    return (t.Id === id);
  });
  return found.length ? found[0].Name : null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick resides on using the object on the select's `ng-options` (e.g. `'obj as obj.title'`) and not a property of the object, so that when an item gets selected, it will assign the whole object to the model and not the property.

The problem with this approach is, that you cannot just compare objects (because comparing an object always compares their reference, not the "contents", so that `obj1 == obj2` will never be true, unless they are exact the same object), so the other trick needed here is to use `track by <some-id-property>` on the ng-options. So your editable would look like this:

```
 <span editable-select="data.organisation.OrganisationType"
        e-ng-options="type as type.Name for type in data.types track by type.Id">
        {{data.organisation.OrganisationType.Name}}
 </span>
```

Beware that on your JSFiddle you're using a very old version of angular (where track by is not supported), so I created a new one using 1.2, which is the oldest angular version supporting track by:

http://jsfiddle.net/NBhn4/170/